# How to convert certain Latin characters to Cyrillic characters

Tags: javascript

I have a question regarding this script, namely, when entering on the Latin keyboard the character `nj` will not convert to `њ` and so as far as the characters `lj` are concerned it does not convert it to `љ` and so on ...

```
if (!Array.prototype.indexOf) {
  Array.prototype.indexOf = function (obj, fromIndex) {
    if (fromIndex == null) {
        fromIndex = 0;
    } else if (fromIndex < 0) {
        fromIndex = Math.max(0, this.length + fromIndex);
    }
    for (var i = fromIndex, j = this.length; i < j; i++) {
        if (this[i] === obj)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
  };
}

function keyupEmail (p_field) {
  m_key = new String();
  m_key = fix_email_chars (p_field.value);  
  p_field.value = m_key;  
}

function fix_email_chars (p_value) {
  var m_to_fix = new Array ("a", "b", "v", "g", "d", "đ", 
                           "e", "ž", "z", "i", "j", "k", 
                           "l", "lj", "m", "n", "nj", "o", 
                           "p", "r", "s", "t", "c", "u", 
                           "f", "h", "c", "c", "dz", "s", 
                           "A", "B", "V", "G", "D", "Đ", 
                           "E", "Ž", "Z", "I", "J", "K", 
                           "L", "LJ", "M", "N", "NJ", "O", 
                           "P", "R", "S", "T", "C", "U", 
                           "F", "H", "C", "C", "DZ", "S", 
                           "s", "đ", "c", "c", "ž", 
                           "S", "D", "C", "C", "Ž");

  var m_fixed = new Array ("а", "б", "в", "г", "д", "ђ", 
                            "е", "ж", "з", "и", "ј", "к", 
                            "л", "љ", "м", "н", "њ", "о", 
                            "п", "р", "с", "т", "ћ", "у", 
                            "ф", "х", "ц", "ч", "џ", "ш", 
                            "А", "Б", "В", "Г", "Д", "Ђ", 
                            "Е", "Ж", "З", "И", "Ј", "К", 
                            "Л", "Љ", "М", "Н", "Њ", "О", 
                            "П", "Р", "С", "Т", "Ћ", "У", 
                            "Ф", "Х", "Ц", "Ч", "Џ", "Ш", 
                            "š", "đ", "č", "ć", "ž", "Š", 
                            "Đ", "Č", "Ć", "Ž");

  var m_value = p_value;

//  alert (p_value);

  var m_output = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < p_value.length; i++) {
    m_index = m_to_fix.indexOf (p_value.charAt(i));
    if (m_index > -1) {
      m_output += m_fixed[m_index];
    } else { 
      m_output += p_value.charAt(i);
    };
  };
                        
  return (m_output);

};
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest but not most efficient way would be to run *"lj" "nj" "dz" "dj"* checks before you convert all characters

Example you have word "**abcljabc**"
You go through whole string and change all double to single letters and get
**abcљabc**
And then you run your mapper that you already built on that result string to get final solution

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is to create an object for double characters, with their respective replacements. Then, inside a for loop, you can check if combo of those double chars exists, and add the value to output accordingly.
I have left comments in the code, to help you out.

```js
function fix_email_chars(p_value) {
  var m_to_fix = new Array("a", "b", "v", "g", "d", "đ",
    "e", "ž", "z", "i", "j", "k",
    "l", "lj", "m", "n", "nj", "o",
    "p", "r", "s", "t", "c", "u",
    "f", "h", "c", "c", "dz", "s",
    "A", "B", "V", "G", "D", "Đ",
    "E", "Ž", "Z", "I", "J", "K",
    "L", "LJ", "M", "N", "NJ", "O",
    "P", "R", "S", "T", "C", "U",
    "F", "H", "C", "C", "DZ", "S",
    "s", "đ", "c", "c", "ž",
    "S", "D", "C", "C", "Ž");

  var m_fixed = new Array("а", "б", "в", "г", "д", "ђ",
    "е", "ж", "з", "и", "ј", "к",
    "л", "љ", "м", "н", "њ", "о",
    "п", "р", "с", "т", "ћ", "у",
    "ф", "х", "ц", "ч", "џ", "ш",
    "А", "Б", "В", "Г", "Д", "Ђ",
    "Е", "Ж", "З", "И", "Ј", "К",
    "Л", "Љ", "М", "Н", "Њ", "О",
    "П", "Р", "С", "Т", "Ћ", "У",
    "Ф", "Х", "Ц", "Ч", "Џ", "Ш",
    "š", "đ", "č", "ć", "ž", "Š",
    "Đ", "Č", "Ć", "Ž");

  let dObj = {}
  let m_output = "";
  m_to_fix.forEach((m, i) => {
    if (m.length == 2) dObj[m] = m_fixed[i];    //Assign Replacements for double letters in the object
  })

  let doubles = ["l", "n", "d", "L", "N", "D"]; //Array of 1st letter of all double letters



  for (var i = 0; i < p_value.length; i += 1) {
    let char = p_value[i];

    if (doubles.includes(char)) {               //Check if char exist in the doubles array
      let char2 = p_value[i + 1];               //Get the immediate next charcater. 

      if ((char + char2) in dObj) {             //Check if char+char2 exists in the object
        m_output += dObj[char + char2];         //If it is, add the replacement to the output
      } else {
        let ind = m_to_fix.indexOf(char);      //Else add replacement of each char individually
        m_output += m_fixed[ind]         
        
        ind = m_to_fix.indexOf(char2);
        m_output += m_fixed[ind] 
      }
      i += 1;                                  //Manually increase index by 1 since, we also checked for next char (char2) to avoid repition
    } else {
      let ind = m_to_fix.indexOf(char);        //Else if char doesn't exist in doubles array, get the index of that char from m_to_fix array
      m_output += m_fixed[ind]                 //add the respective replacement of from the m_fixed array
    } 
  }

  return m_output;

};


console.log(fix_email_chars("njalj"))
```

Comment: @Dejo Please check if this helps.